# Unable to sort and remove duplicates in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sorting

I'm currently would like to sort a list of Object on LINQ, where I need to Sort and Remove Duplication if founded. It would be easier if I provide simple example for my scenario.

This is my current list (I have simplified it and sorted):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "userActivityId": 17,
      "deviceId": 2,
      "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 32 GB",
      "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
    },
    {
      "userActivityId": 16,
      "deviceId": 1,
      "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 16 GB",
      "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
    },
    {
      "userActivityId": 15,
      "deviceId": 1,
      "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 16 GB",
      "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
    },
    {
      "userActivityId": 14,
      "deviceId": 2,
      "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 32 GB",
      "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
    },
  ]
}
```

**Expected Result**

What I really wanted:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "userActivityId": 17,
      "deviceId": 2,
      "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 32 GB",
      "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
    },
    {
      "userActivityId": 16,
      "deviceId": 1,
      "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 16 GB",
      "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
    },
  ]
}
```

Here we can see then `userActivityId` `15` and `14` is removed, because the `name` already existed there.

So we can sort unique by using `name`.

**What I have tried**

**First Attempt**

This is the original code for the sorting functionality.

```
var data = new leapserverdbContext().TbUserActivity
            .OrderByDescending(id => id.UserActivityId)
            .Select(sel => new
            {
                sel.UserActivityId,
                sel.TbDevice.DeviceId,
                Name = sel.TbDevice.TbDeviceBrand.Name + " " + sel.TbDevice.Name +
                    " " + sel.TbDevice.TbDeviceYear.Year + " " + sel.TbDevice.TbDeviceSize.Size,
                    sel.TbDevice.IconResource                             
            })
            .ToList();
```

**Second Attempt**

I try to put `Distinct()`, but it won't work because there is `userActivityId` and it is unique (because incrementing).

**Third Attempt**

I try to remove `userActivityId`, to avoid it being considered while `Distinct()`, but then my data wont be sorted. Because sorting depends
on `userActivityId`.

**Forth Attempt**

I tried using `GroupBy (x => x.Name)`, so focus divide based on unique Name.
But it just start dividing them into array as provided below:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "userActivityId": 16,
        "deviceId": 1,
        "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 16 GB",
        "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
      },
      {
        "userActivityId": 15,
        "deviceId": 1,
        "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 16 GB",
        "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
      }     
    ],
    [
      {
        "userActivityId": 17,
        "deviceId": 2,
        "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 32 GB",
        "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
      },
      {
        "userActivityId": 14,
        "deviceId": 2,
        "name": "Apple Iphone X 2013 32 GB",
        "iconResource": "phone_apple_iphone_x.jpg"
      }

    ]
  ]
}
```

Now it is sorted and divided based on their unique `name`. But the layout is complete different.

What in my mind would do is get the first array (As it is the latest), but how can I combine and produce the `Expected Result` (See Above).

Is there anyway to solve this small problem of mine?

Comment: what is considered duplicate? having same `userActivityId` or should all values be the same to be considered as duplicate?

Comment: Why not skip the two ids in your Select statement if you don't need em at all?

Comment: duplication based on their `name`. and I wont need `userActivityId` as their basis

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from using an `EqualityComparer` like previously suggested you could also just group your result on name-property since you in this case are using an anonymous type.

```
var data = new leapserverdbContext().TbUserActivity
        .OrderByDescending(id => id.UserActivityId)
        .Select(sel => new
        {
            sel.UserActivityId,
            sel.TbDevice.DeviceId,
            Name = sel.TbDevice.TbDeviceBrand.Name + " " + sel.TbDevice.Name +
                " " + sel.TbDevice.TbDeviceYear.Year + " " + sel.TbDevice.TbDeviceSize.Size,
            sel.TbDevice.IconResource
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried your method, I need multiple sort `for the name` and `overall`. As after `.Select(g => g.First())` I need to put `.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserActivityId)` and it works. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Equality Comparer:

```
    public class ActivityComparer : IEqualityComparer<TbUserActivity>
    {
        public bool Equals(TbUserActivity x, TbUserActivity y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return true;
            else if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;
            return x.name == y.name 
        }

        public int GetHashCode(TbUserActivity obj)
        {
            return obj.userActivityId;
        }
    }
```

And then just:

```
result.Distinct(new ActivityComparer());
```

Comment: When I tried to put `result.Distinct(new ActivityComparer());` it gives me Distinct() not found error

Comment: you mean there is not `Distinct()` method?

Comment: I think the .GroupBy method and .Select() earlier fixed my problem. I appreciate your help. Thanks.